# contextual type cgfloat cannot be used with array literal

Tags: swift, swift3, uilabel, gradient

I'm using UIImage+Gradient.swift file to add gradient to my label, but I get this error:

> contextual type cgfloat cannot be used with array literal

I've reviewed some FAQ Q&A but I'm still confused.

Here is the code:

```
let components = colors.reduce([]) { (currentResult: [CGFloat], currentColor: UIColor) -> [CGFloat] in
        var result = currentResult
        let numberOfComponents = currentColor.cgColor.numberOfComponents
        let components = currentColor.cgColor.components
        if numberOfComponents == 2 {
            result.append([components?[0], components?[0], components?[0], components?[1]])
        } else {
            result.append([components?[0], components?[1], components?[2], components?[3]])
        }
        return result
    }
```

Lines which are giving error are these:

> result.append([components?[0], components?[0], components?[0], components?[1]])
>   result.append([components?[0], components?[1], components?[2], components?[3]])

Answer (score 2):

This error has to do with trying to make a variable that is not an array be set to an array. For example this would produce a similar error:

```
var myFavSnacks:String = ["Apples","Grasses","Carrots"] //gives similar error
```

In your case, it thinks you want to add an array of CGFloats to one index in your array, rather than adding a number of CGFloats to your array.

To add multiple items to an array at once use `contentsOf:` like this:

```
colors.append(contentsOf: ["red", "blue"]) 
//adds strings "red" and "blue" to an existing array of strings called colors
```

From documentation available here:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array